# Nyromodal, as a non-modal dialog

Tags: jquery, nyromodal

Maybe I am being ridiculous, but is there any way to get Nyromodal to stop being modal and be allowed multiple dialogs, even if there on the same z-index is fine I just need to be able to have 2 dialogs up without darkening the background. Is this possible? calling on all nyro-gurus on this one.

NOTE: 
   I have set modal to false, closeOnClick to false, and at a loss...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the stack setting to true in order to allow multiple nyroModal on the same page (only available on the version 2)

if you want to remove the background, edit the CSS and set background: none; for .nyroModalBg